# Is uClibc only used in Linux based Operating Systems?

Tags: c, linux, uclibc, c-standard-library

uClibc (or uClibc-ng) is stated as a C library for embedded Linux systems. The documentation cites Linux everywhere and say the library is very carefully optimized for Linux.

Although the library has been specially developed to be used in Linux, is it also useful to other systems? Is there any restrictions one needs to know when using the library with other OSes?

Comment: what other OSes would you have in mind?

Comment: If it is optimized to Linux, it probably uses system calls that are unique to Linux and therefore won’t readily port to other platforms that don’t have full support for all the Linux system calls.

Comment: @avigil, I'm writing a POSIX PSE51 compliant OS. To comply with the standard there are lots of C standard library functionalities the OS needs to provide. I don't want to reinvent the wheel so I'd like to use one of the open source libc's that exist out there instead of writing my own.

Comment: Linux is "mostly POSIX compliant" which means there will probably be things specific to linux that will break the library